# Why is the word "Talmud" censored?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, jewish-books

In Megillah 2a, Rashi [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Megillah.2a.18.2):

> שמצינו בכמה מקומות **בשם** ר"א בר' יוסי סתימתאי

Regardless of the context there, as it's not needed for this question, Oz Vehadar brings from Dikdukei Sofrim (I don't have a copy so I assume they quote it correctly):

> בכת"י ובדפו"ר איתר בכמה מקומות **בתלמוד**, ובדפוסים המאוחרים שינו מפני הצענזור **בש"ס** (כמו שעשו כן בכל הש"ס), ומזה נשתבש אח"כ לתיבת "בשם"י

It basically writes that the word "בשם" in Rashi is a typo, as it used to be "בש"ס", which was after the censors changed the word "Talmud" throughout Shas to...Shas.

I'm wondering why the censors would change the word Talmud? What's offensive about it? It had bad connotations? Bonus question is was this censorship only found in the Talmud or in other seforim as well.

Comment: It was not that they censored the word Talmud it was that they banned the Talmud so we began calling it Shas (_Shisha Sederim_) to avoid the ban. "Oh, we're not studying the Talmud, we're studying 'Shas'." ;)